# free to charge to meaning in this context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> The MATERIALS shall be delivered to Receiving Parties (i) (*omitted*) and (ii) **free to charge to Receiving Parties**.

My question is, what does the phrase in bold mean in this context? Is it saying that Receiving Parties will or will not bear the cost of delivery? Kindly let me know if it is grammatically correct. 
Thank you.

Comment: I would assume it’s a typo and should be “free **of** change” instead

Comment: Can you provide the source of the sentence in question?

Comment: It is from a material transfer contract between thee organizations. In that sentence, a party is being obligated to deliver the materials to Receiving Parties.

Comment: **shall be ... free to charge to** makes no sense to me, and I've read a lot of contracts in my day. Are the markers "(i)" and "(ii)" in the original, and is there a possibility that you've omitted something from (i) that is syntactically relevant to (ii)?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I've come across plenty of things stating that someone will *be* "**free to charge**" something. That means that they have the freedom to set a price or bill someone for something. You could say:

> Hotels are free to charge whatever they like for pay-per-view.

However, that makes very little sense here. How can something be *delivered* in such a way that they can bill the receiving parties? I mean, if you try to parse it with that meaning you end up with the idea that the materials will, once they are delivered, be able to bill the people who received them in some way. That makes no sense.

It could be a typo for ***free of charge***, which would mean, by my understanding and in such a contract, that there could be no extra charge for delivery beyond the price agreed in the contract. If it's a contract for ongoing supply, it's agreeing that all prices agreed will be inclusive of delivery.

There is one other use of ***free to charge***, though, which is in relation to electric vehicles. If you have a *free to charge* contract for your vehicle, you can use charging points that are part of the provider's network without paying anyone anything further in future. You also get *free to charge* charging points that someone has decided to install and allow anyone to charge as much as they like and not pay anything. Without knowing what the materials are, that meaning seems very unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Panda mentioned, it should be "free **of** charge."

> Is it saying that Receiving Parties will or will not bear the cost of delivery?

It is saying that Receiving Parties **will not** bear the cost of delivery.